# How do you get values from html and set them in the view for example if you wanted to create a new table row in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

This is my current Html i would like to grab the rootname and the currentplatform from my root table and create a new row on my log table using the root name.

```
      <div id="container">
    <div id = "left" >
     {%for status in root|slice:":1" %}
    <h1><center>Root List by {{status.rootgroup}} Rootgroup<center></h1>
    {% endfor %}
        <h3 id="time">current:  </h3>
        <table border = "2">

            <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>   Check All</th>
                <th>Rootname </th>
                <td>Urls</td>
                <th> custs </th>
                <th> jvmms </th>
                <th> x64 </th>
                <th> currentplatform </th>
                <th> currentjdk </th>
                <th> currenttomcat </th>
                <td><p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" size="10" /></p></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="12:00" size="5" /><td>
            <select name="ampm">
                <option value="am">AM</option>
                <option value="pm">PM</option>
            </select>
            </tr>
                {% for status in root %}


            <tr >
            <form name= "/display2/" method="POST">


            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" onclick="resetSelectedAll(this);" id="row{{ forloop.counter }}" ></td>

                <td name = "root" id="row{{forloop.counter}}rootname">{{ status.rootname }}</td>

                <td name= "server" id="row{{forloop.counter}}urls">{{ status.urls }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}custs">{{ status.custs }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}jvmms"> {{ status.jvmms }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}x64">{{ status.x64 }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currentplatform"> {{ status.currentplatform }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currentjdk"> {{ status.currentjdk }}</td>
                <td id="row{{forloop.counter}}currenttomcat">{{ status.currenttomcat }}</td>
            </tr>

                {% endfor %}



        </table>

        <select name="action">
            <option value="Restart">Restart</option>
            <option value="Full_Dump">Full_Dump</option>
            <option value="Redeploy">Redeploy</option>
            <option value="Thread">Thread</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" onclick="check()" value="submit"/>
```

This is my current view i would like to replace the stuff surrounded in asterix with text from my html which will then create a new row in a different table based on the information i choose. I tried using forms, but i do not want to input data i already have the data displayed just need to call it or connect the 2 going backwards.

```
def display2(request, value=None):
    log = Logofsupport._meta.get_all_field_names()
    rootFilter = Viewroot.objects.filter(rootstatus__gt=0, type =1, jvmms=1024, rootgroup =     value).distinct()#Root List by RootGroup
    if request.method == 'POST':

        log = LogofsupportForm(request.POST)
      #  action = request.Get.get('action')
        if log.is_valid:
           new = LogofsupportForm**(servername="appBOWSERtest032", rootname="appBOWSERtest032",requesteddate='07/16/2013', action="restart", loginname="justin")**
           new.save()
        else:
            log= LogofsupportForm()
    return render_to_response('status/root_server.html', { 'root' : rootFilter, 'log': log },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what the objective of your process is, but I think the answer to your question is to create the string of HTML you want in your python code instead of using the template file.

In other words, take the tr with all the forloop.counters and recreate it in a string in a python function. Then load that string as a template variable, in effect pasting in each HTML row inside the template. Then inside your logging function, you can call the same python function that creates each row, effectively "importing" it.

It is possible to "get the HTML", but that would require some kind of asynchronous request via Javascript that sends the HTML you want as an HTTP request argument. There is a library called [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) which can automate the process of sending asynchronous javascript requests to Django, but for your purposes it would be much less difficult to simply refactor the way you are creating the HTML.

Comment: If i am not mistaken i already have the string of html in my python code. I am displaying a group of tables in a html table then based on which you clicked adding that row to another table as a new row.